# HTML5 canvas not updating: browser bug or am I doing something wrong?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I have some HTML 5 code that starts out with two black canvases and then updates the canvases one row at a time by drawing a red line for each row.  It is supposed to look like a red curtain dropping down over the black background.

The odd part is that at first it looks like random rows (say 5%) are being skipped and left black. I thought I had a bug.  But then I noticed that if I resized the browser window that the black lines all turned red.  So then I thought it was some sort of browser repaint bug.  Then I noticed that both Chrome and Safari have this behavior.

So do you think both these browsers have the same bug or am I doing something wrong?

Interestingly, this issue goes away if both canvases use style="width:100%; height:100%".

```
<html>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><canvas id="myCanvas1" style="width:100%; height:100%"></canvas></td>
        <td><canvas id="myCanvas2" style="width:200px; height:400px"></canvas></td>
    </tr>
</table>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var canvases = [document.getElementById("myCanvas1"), document.getElementById("myCanvas2")];

    for(var i = 0; i < canvases.length; i++) {
        var canvas = canvases[i];
        var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
        ctx.fillStyle = "black";
        ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    }

    function updateRow(rowNum) { 

        var done = true;
        for(var i = 0; i < canvases.length; i++) {
            var canvas = canvases[i];

            if(rowNum >= canvas.height) {
                return;
            }
            done = false;

            var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

            var imageDataForRow = ctx.getImageData(0, rowNum, canvas.width, 1);

            for(var offset = 0; offset < imageDataForRow.data.length; offset += 4) {
                imageDataForRow.data[offset] = 255;
                imageDataForRow.data[offset + 1] = 0;
                imageDataForRow.data[offset + 2] = 0;
                imageDataForRow.data[offset + 3] = 255;
            }

            ctx.putImageData(imageDataForRow, 0, rowNum);
        }

        if(!done) {
            var paintNextRow = function() {
                updateRow(rowNum + 1);
            }
            setTimeout(paintNextRow, 1);
        }
    }

    updateRow(0);

</script>
```

Comment: Chrome, Safari = Yes.  Firefox = No.  IE = won't even render (probably unrelated to issue at hand).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is your problem:

`<canvas id="myCanvas1" style="width:100%; height:100%">`

You are setting the width and height of the Canvas using CSS width and height and not the `<canvas>` html attributes. You are literally stretching a canvas sized 300x150 (the default) to skew across the entire screen.

You need to define the width/height either in the canvas tag:`<canvas width="500" height="500">`

or in code:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
canvas.width = 500;
canvas.height = 500;
```

And not by CSS. If you did this:

`<canvas style="width: 500px; height: 500px;">`

Then you would have a 300x150 canvas (the default size) that was scaled/warped to be 500x500, which is almost certainly what you're getting.

---

It looks like you want to have the canvas width change dynamically. This is OK, but you have to do one of a few things. One would be to use the window's `onresize` event, and set the canvas width equal to the div's clientWidth every time this happens (if the clientWidth has changed of course). The other would be to do a simple general timer to check for the same thing every half-second or so, and set `canvas.width` equal to the `div.style.clientWidth`.

(I wrote the above freehand so there might be a typo, but you get the idea)

Comment: Interesting.  Didn't know 100% would be a stretch. Changing to width="500" height="500" fixes the issue.  Assuming I wanted to do a stretch (and I don't) I still think the black lines could be justified as a bug.  How do I stretch a red line into being a black line?

Comment: its a visual artifact from trying to stretch red lines over a black background, it doesn't guarantee that skewed lines won't let some of the background (a black canvas) show through.